# Minimum code for mDNS browsing

Tags: python, sublimetext3, zeroconf, mdns

I'm developing a Sublime Text plugin to work with IoT devices. Some of that hardwares have the option to upload the code by OTA (over the air) and I need to be able to discover the device by mDNS.

I've tried with **zeroconf** and it works very well, I just need to set the browser like that:

`browser = ServiceBrowser(zeroconf, "_arduino._tcp.local.", listener)`

**So, what is the problem?**

Sublime Text runs the plugins in it's own simplified version, so the only way to run an external package is downloading and integrating it into the plugin code. all is fine there, I've done with other packages without problem.

[zeroconf](https://github.com/jstasiak/python-zeroconf) has the following dependencies: `enum-compat, netifaces, six` and some of that dependencies has its own dependencies.

I tried downloading each dependency (and it seems to much code only to browse), but the main problem is that netifaces is written in `C`. I tested some things to try to make it work but I didn't make it.

I've also tried with this repository [zeroconf](https://github.com/wmcbrine/pyzeroconf) It's and old version of the zeroconf above and not need the netifaces dependence. The code to browse is the same in both cases, but in this old version it's not getting any arduino device.

**So what do I need?**

I would like to get help with a code to browse/discover the arduino devices, as I previously described the main goal is get a minimum code to this task and run without install any dependence. I mean download the depedence if it needs and execute it locally.

I don't want someone to write me the code, but someone to may point me where can I start.

I've been looking the zeroconf code and it seems that it's not possible to work without netifaces, and that is the reason why the old repository didn't find the devices.

**I've also tried with:**

- [mdns](https://github.com/svinota/mdns) This seems to be a non dependence code, but there is not documentation, so I didn't make it work
- [mdns-lookup](https://github.com/AndreMiras/mdns-lookup) It find other devices, but not the arduino/esp type

Comment: So post the code: [mcve]

Comment: So... I think you don't understand part of my question. That is what I'm asking... not someone to make the code but someone to tell me where do I should start, I've tried with some codes but most of them use the zeroconf library that I can't use.

Comment: Remove the dependencies.  They are not extensive.